# What are stub applications?

Tags: macos, applications, java, binary

I am trying to understand how and where Java is installed on my Mac (Mavericks this time) and I found this question and answers:

- [Need help understanding Oracle's Java on Mac — Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120745/need-help-understanding-oracles-java-on-mac)

Here is mentioned

> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands. The binaries within that directory are stub applications

What are stub applications? They are not symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stub applications are smaller apps that do work for larger, more complex apps.

For example, an app can request information from a stub app concurrently with a main process that the original app is running. Then, the stub app can return information back to the main process that initiated the stub binary.

Comment: So, how do I find "JavaApplicationStub" in my computer when an app asks for it?